# What is the best password management practice while on server (ubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, passwords, password-protection

I am running server provisioning with a big bash file, but not sure how to handle passwords and other similar sensitive information. At this point I just have lots of environmental variables, etc:

```
export HOME=/home/deployer
export DBuser=happy
export DBpass=pass
export AMAZONKEY=AKIAIWDGW3KDY2TZ7PVYA
```

and afterwards I just use these values, etc $DBuser anywhere I want. But if to some unfortunate event somebody would gain access to my server, by simply running "printenv" will gain all my passwords. What is the best strategy to have a centralized place or strategy for managing this sensitive information?

Comment: What tools are involved here? Where do you need the passwords exactly? What resources do you have at the point where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Create an OS user for your application

Store the environment variables for that user only

Run the application as that user

Other users/programs won't be able to see those environment variables (except root)